# Set min and max value in double for y-axis in highchart

Tags: javascript, java, highcharts

I am Using HighCharts to generate charts.I want to set values of the Y Axis in double with decimal points but it show value as integer in graph.I want the chart to start at 50.5 with intervals of 50 like the next point will be at 100.5. As shown in below link

[Demo Link in JSfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zapzadmp/4/)

```
  yAxis: {
         min:50.5,
         max:250.5,
         tickInterval:50
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong ?, 
when you hover it shows the correct value

Comment: See Y-axis start value is 50 not 50.5.I want to show 50.5 in y-axis.

Comment: check docs https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.allowDecimals

Comment: You can see in doc Defaults to true.I tried this but it's not working.

Comment: You have a problem here as your tick interval is 50 there wont be a point in 50.5 or 250.5 so you should try changing your tick interval and you cant set min max without a tick interval

Comment: Brother my Y-axis values are fixed.say my start point is 50.5 and my second point is 100.5. So my tick interval is 50.

Comment: but highchart will require you to have the tick interval at 50.5 as from 0 - first point you have 50.5

Comment: my min value is 50.5 so my highchart will take that as a start value rather then 0.

Comment: i tried and seems like thats not how high chart works :(

Comment: This is caused by [`startOnTick`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.startOnTick) and [`endOnTick`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick). Once disabled you will get expected extremes: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zapzadmp/27/ If you want ticks 50.5 and so on, the best is to use [`tickPositions`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions) or [`tickPositioner`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue using tickPositions.

```
yAxis: {
 tickPositions: [50.5, 100.5, 150.5, 200.5, 250.5]  
}
```

[Solved Answer Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zapzadmp/26/)